# Switching only one AC side live/netural using Triac/SCR

Tags: ac, triac, scr

I was wondering if Triacs/SCRs can be used for switching only one side of AC (neutral or live), or whether there are other component that I can use for this.

The load is an AC motor, and the current around 8A, and I am thinking of connecting live wire to the motor; and neutral to the Triac T1 and then T2 to the motor.

I have the schematic here, but I am not sure if it will work if I only connect neutral to it (i.e exactly like a switch).

I guess in this case the snubber circuit (RV1, C1, and R4) won't be needed.

[image]

Edit #1: a clearer schematic on how I am planning to connect the load.[image]

Comment: On a side note, avoid connecting the LED D1 and the optocoupler's LED in parallel. The might have different forward voltages (your LED might be red, optocouplers are usually IR). This will cause one of them to never light up. Use independent series resistors for both LEDs or connect the LEDs in series.

Comment: Yes, you are right; I have replaced it with two independent resistors. (330 and 1k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I guess in this case the snubber circuit (RV1, C1, and R4) won't be
> needed.*

If they are needed when switching the live then they will be needed when switching the neutral. The circuit is optically coupled and won't care whether you switch live or neutral.

Apart from anything else, on many installations where circuits like this are used, you are not in control of whether live or neutral are connected to the triac.

Comment: Thank you so much, my confusion is that if I am connecting only neutral --for example-- then that is only one side so the capacitor/varistor terminals are connected to the same AC side and won't do anything, is that assumption correct?

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how you can say that. Let me be clear about this; the motor can connect to AC1 or to AC2 of connector J3. Live or neutral connects to the terminal of J3 that the motor doesn't use. If neutral connects to J3 then live connects to the other motor terminal and vice versa if live connects to J3 @MohamedEl-Sayed

Comment: Thank you, this makes total sense now, while I was updating the schematics; that became clear to me.

The confusing bit was maybe because I was thinking in DC and not AC, and how the current will flow "through" the load and then to the switching circuit.

Do you think the circuit would work in principle?

Comment: @MohamedEl-Sayed it's a standard circuit. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.